# WordPress and External API

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, api

I'm attempting to use an AJAX call to post to an external API. I primarily want to do this to protect the API Key from prying eyes, though I'm a little lost on where to go with this next.

I've defined the API Key in my WP_config.php file and am able to echo that back in a PHP file. I've created a PHP file that creates a shortcode and added it to my custom post page template. I'd like to call a PHP function to handle the AJAX request to obfuscate the API Key and return the result so I can then modify the interface to notify the user that the feedback has been received. The shortcode works well and the form is posting correctly based on the console.log.

This is my page-feedback.php plugin code at the moment but I don't know where to go next. I was investigating the WP Rest API but I don't need to leverage any the WP functionality for this. Can I reference this existing PHP file for handling posting to the API? How would I approach that?

```
// Initialization
defined('ABSPATH') or die('Unauthorized access.');
add_shortcode('page-feedback', 'page_feedback_shortcode');
add_action('wp_footer', 'load_scripts');

function page_feedback_shortcode()

{ ?>

<div class="page-feedback">
    <form id="page-feedback-form__form">
        <input name="page" type="hidden" value="<?php echo urlencode(get_the_permalink()) ?>" />
        <input name="username" type="hidden" value="<?php echo wp_get_current_user()->user_login ?>" />
        <input id="page-feedback-form-helpful" name="helpful" type="hidden" />
        <p id="page-feedback-form-helpfulQuestion">Was this page helpful? <button type="submit">Yes</button> or <button type="submit">No</button></p>
    </form>
</div>

<?php }

function load_scripts()
{ ?>
<script>
    jQuery('#page-feedback-form__form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = jQuery(this).serialize();
        console.log(form);

        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '',
            data: form,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: You have two main problems that need to be solved, and although one leads to the other, the are in no other way related. Server-side, you need to make an API. Client-side, you need to make an AJAX POST to the same server? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that to be the case. I looked into creating an API endpoint with the WP REST API but it requires a namespace which I wasn't sure where to point it if it's just referencing itself to then post externally. The AJAX POST should be straight forward once I figure out how to call the PHP endpoint that does the POST.

Comment: The namespace is meant to differentiate the endpoint from any other vendor's implementation using the same endpoint name and, therefore, it should be included in the route. Example: acme/v1/messages, momcorp/v1/messages... Just choose a name that matches your theme, plugin, or company.